# Use Simple HTML DOM parser with curl for gzip url

Tags: php, curl

I wanted to get and process a web page with *file_get_html()* function. So I tried to do it optimally with curl function as follows:

```
function file_get_html_new($url, $use_include_path = false, $context=null)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $context );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    $contents = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if (empty($contents) || strlen($contents) > MAX_FILE_SIZE)
    {
        return false;
    }
    $dom->load($contents, $lowercase, $stripRN);
    return $dom;
}
$html = file_get_html_new( 'http://***.us/'. $imdb_id , false , array('Host: ***.us',
'Connection: keep-alive',
'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36',
'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch',
'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fa;q=0.6',
'Cookie: ***',
'AlexaToolbar-ALX_NS_PH: AlexaToolbar/alx-4.0'));
```

But I faced the below error running the code:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function load() on a non-object
```

By getting results of curl function like this:

```
function file_get_html_new($url, $use_include_path = false, $context=null)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $context );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    $contents = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if (empty($contents) || strlen($contents) > MAX_FILE_SIZE)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //$dom->load($contents, $lowercase, $stripRN);
    echo $contents;
}
```

Some vague and unclear results were shown, I found that it happened because contents were "gzip"ed. I decompressed them like this:

```
$contents = gzinflate( substr(curl_exec($ch),10,-8) );
```

and try this too:

```
$contents = gzdecode (curl_exec($ch));
```

Now I have the correct contents but the error is still there! Can you help me understand why that is?

Comment: You are using the `$dom` variable inside your function but there is no such variable there...

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. There's no need to plead for help or to thank anyone in advance - both the questions and the answers are in a sense a public service; people would not be answering *you* but rather *your question*, for many others to see. See also [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/196834) of this issue.